# How work java lambda? I can not understand

Tags: java, lambda

I have started to learn Java lambda and I do not understand it. I found an  example.

```
 String[] atp = {"Rafael Nadal", "Novak Djokovic", "Stanislas Wawrinka", "David Ferrer", "Roger Federer", "Andy Murray", "Tomas Berdych", "Juan Martin Del Potro"};

players.forEach((player) -> System.out.print(player + "; "));
```

And it works fine, but my code does not work.

```
public class Counter {

    String[] atp = {"Rafael Nadal", "Novak Djokovic", "Stanislas Wawrinka", "David Ferrer", "Roger Federer", "Andy Murray", "Tomas Berdych", "Juan Martin Del Potro"};
    List<String> players =  Arrays.asList(atp);
    private int a = 7;
    private int b = 7;

    public int summ(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    public void print(){
        players.forEach((player) -> System.out.print(player + "; "));
        summ((a,b)-> System.out.print(a + b));
    }
}
```

I want understand how lambda works.

This is not working - 
    `summ((a,b)-> System.out.print(a + b));`

Comment: Have a look : [What is lambda ?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1086347/4290096)

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambdas with functional interfaces.

### **What is a functional interface?**

It is basically an interface that has one and only **abstract method** (*but can have other default methods for example*)

The most frequent example is the [`Predicate`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/function/Predicate.java) interface.

```
public interface Predicate <T> {
    boolean test(T t);
    // Other methods
}
```

This one take any Object (generics) and returns a boolean primitive.

So let's say we want to test a condition using this interface to find pair numbers in a loop, we code the following.

```
Predicate<Integer> function = a -> a%2 == 0;

for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
    if (function.test(i)){         // The primitive is AutoBoxed into an Integer Object here
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```