# Creating Inline Functions and Macros

Tags: c#, function, macros, inline

I know this is wrong (trying to code in C# with a C/C++ mindset).
But is it possible to create inline functions / inline recursive functions (til the Nth call) / macros in C#?

Because if I intend to call the same function 1000 times, but it's a simple function, the overhead of creating the stack is quite big... And unnecessary.

In C i could use inline functions. Is there something like that in C#?

Again... I'm not saying that C/C++ is better... I'm just new to C# and have none to ask those simple questions...

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900069/how-to-make-inline-functions-on-c-sharp

Comment: 1000 times I wouldn't worry about.  I regularly call deep into my stack in tight performance loops.  The compiler does some optimization for you although it's frustrating to not know how much.  If I needed better performance than that, I wouldn't nickle and dime over stack depth, but just go implement it in C++ and sit closer to the hardware to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Inline functions in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473782/inline-functions-in-c)

> Finally in .NET 4.5, the CLR allows one to force1 method inlining
>   using [MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) value. It is also available
>   in the Mono's trunk (committed today).

```
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)] 
void Func()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello Inline");
}
```

Comment: I see. So even tho there WAS no 'force inlining' the compiler could still inline some functions. Do you know any case where we should use the "NoInlining" MethodImpOption?

Comment: @Trauer The only uses of it that I'm familiar with are for diagnostic purposes to test whether or not methods are being inlined, or what the performance affects are of it being inlined.  I know of know uses for it in a production app.

Comment: @Servy, in some cases compiler will do inlining as part of optimization .. right? (not able to remember exactly, so confirming)

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be: don't worry about it.  No need to start with micro-optimizations unless you've tested it and it's actually a problem.  1000 function calls is nothing until it's something.  This is majorly overshadowed by a single network call.  Write your program.  Check the performance against the goals.  If it's not performant enough, use a profiler and figure out where your problem spots are.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, C# is a very powerful general purpose language that can do nearly anything.  While, inline functions / macros are generally frowned upon, C# does provide you with multiple tools that can accomplish this in a more concise and precise fashion.  For example, you may consider using template files which can be used (and reused) in nearly all forms of .NET applications (web, desktop, console, etc).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx

From the article:

> **What Can T4 Templates Do For Me?**
>
> By combining literal text, imperative code, and processing directives, you can transform data in your environment into buildable artifacts for your project. For example, inside a template you might write some C# or Visual Basic code to call a web service or open an Excel spreadsheet. You can use the information you retrieve from those data sources to generate code for business rules, data validation logic, or data transfer objects. The generated code is available when you compile your application.

If you're new to programming I would recommend against implementing templates.  They are not easy to debug in an N-Tier application because they get generated and ran at run-time.  However, it is an interesting read and opens up many possibilities.