# How to inline methods in .Net 3.5?

Tags: .net, inline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inline functions in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473782/inline-functions-in-c)

Could someone guide me on how to request the .Net compiler to make functions inline? Thanks

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473782/inline-functions-in-c

Comment: You cannot force it on .NET 3.5, the jitter optimizer makes the decision.  You can only *prevent* a method from getting inlined.

Comment: @HansPassant How can we prevent a method from getting inlined? And why we would need to do that?

Comment: Use the [MethodImpl] attribute.  You'd typically only do that to get better exception stack traces that show the method name.  It won't show up if the method gets inlined.