# LINQ List.AsParallel with boolean return

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, plinq

I've got a `static List<long> primes` of all known primes up to a certain point, and a function like this:

```
static bool isPrime(long p)
{
    double rootP = Math.Sqrt(p);

    foreach (long q in primes)
    {
        if (p % q == 0)
            return false;

        if (q >= rootP)
            return true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

which could be parallelised like this:

```
static bool isPrime(long p)
{
    double rootP = Math.Sqrt(p);

    primes.AsParallel().ForAll(q =>
        {
            if (p % q == 0)
                return false;

            if (q > rootP)
                break;
        });

    return true;
}
```

However, this gives a compile-time error saying some return types in my block aren't implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.

I'm somewhat new to LINQ, especially PLINQ. This, to me, seems like a good candidate for parallelism, since the checking of each known prime against the candidate prime is an independent process.

Is there an easy way to fix my block so that it works, or do I need to attack this problem in a completely different way?

Comment: It's got a very short (timewise) inner loop so AsParallel() is unlikely to help much - it will probably be slower than a non parallel loop. You'd be better off using a `Partitioner` along with `Parallel.ForEach()` as shown [in my recent answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16822242/106159) That doesn't directly help with your `return false` problem; you'll have to set a shared bool in the loop and check it in the loops to exit the loops early if necessary, then return the bool after the outer loop has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax-wise, you're making two mistakes in your code:

1. A `return` in a lambda doesn't return from the enclosing method, just from the lambda, so your `return false;` wouldn't work correctly.
2. You can't `break` out of lambda. Even if that lambda is executed in a loop, that loop is basically invisible to you, you certainly can't control it directly.

I think the best way to fix your code is to use a LINQ method made exactly for this purpose: [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383939.aspx), along with `TakeWhile()` to filter out the primes that are too large:

```
static bool IsPrime(long p)
{
    double rootP = Math.Sqrt(p);

    return !primes.AsParallel().TakeWhile(q => q > rootP).Any(q => p % q == 0);
}
```

But there is also a flaw in your reasoning:

> This, to me, seems like a good candidate for parallelism, since the checking of each known prime against the candidate prime is an independent process.

It's not as simple as that. Checking each prime is also an extremely simple process. This means that the overhead of simple parallelization (like the one I suggested above) is likely to be bigger than the performance gains. A more complicated solution (like the one suggested by Matthew Watson in a comment) could help with that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution to your problem:

```
static List<long> primes = new List<long>() {
  2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23
};

static bool isPrime(long p) {
  var sqrt = (long)Math.Sqrt(p);
  if (sqrt * sqrt == p)
    return (false);
  return (primes.AsParallel().All(n => n > sqrt || p % n != 0));
}
```

It even tries to reduce parallelism for quadratic numbers and will stop checking more candidates as soon as the first is found which is

Comment: I'm not sure this is such a big win. If you have a thousand primes and call `isPrime(2)`, you can be sure that this code will unnecessarily check all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because if your condition

```
p % q == 0
```

is `true` the closure will return `false` and when

```
q > rootP
```

it breaks and returns nothing. This will work in PHP but not in .NET :P

A lambda is a full anonymous function and return types allways have to be consistent.

You have to redesign your code here. You have done it right in your non-parallelised example... Just replace `break` with `return true` (it won't be prettier then, but it should work).

Answer (score 0):

It maybe easier to use Parallel.For instead

```
static volatile bool result = true;
static bool isPrime(long p)
{
    double rootP = Math.Sqrt(p);

    Parallel.For(0, primes.Count, (q, state) =>
        {
            if (p % q == 0)
            {
                result = false;
                state.Break();
            }

            if (q > rootP)
                state.Break();
        });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe local variables can be declared as `volatile`; it'd have to be a field member instead.

Comment: @DanLugg: Great observation. I'd expected the `result` variable to be captured by the delegate and lifted by compiler to a member variable anyway, but looks like it doesn't work out. Thanks for your comment.