# Parallel.For vs for

Tags: c#, for-loop, parallel-processing

I have a Parallel.For and a regular for loop doing some simple arithmetic, just to benchmark Parallel.For

My conclusion is that, the regular for is faster on my i5 notebook processor.

This is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Iterations = int.MaxValue / 1000;
            DateTime StartTime = DateTime.MinValue;
            DateTime EndTime = DateTime.MinValue;

            StartTime = DateTime.Now;
            Parallel.For(0, Iterations, i =>
            {
                OperationDoWork(i);
            });
            EndTime = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine(EndTime.Subtract(StartTime).ToString());

            StartTime = DateTime.Now;
            for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
            {
                OperationDoWork(i);
            }
            EndTime = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine(EndTime.Subtract(StartTime).ToString());

            StartTime = DateTime.Now;
            Parallel.For(0, Iterations, i =>
            {
                OperationDoWork(i);
            });
            EndTime = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine(EndTime.Subtract(StartTime).ToString());

            StartTime = DateTime.Now;
            for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
            {
                OperationDoWork(i);
            }
            EndTime = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine(EndTime.Subtract(StartTime).ToString());
        }

        private static void OperationDoWork(int i)
        {
            int a = 0;
            a += i;
            i = a;
            a *= 2;
            a = a * a;
            a = i;
        }
    }
}
```

And these are my results. Which on repetition do not change much:

```
00:00:03.9062234
00:00:01.7971028
00:00:03.2231844
00:00:01.7781017
```

So why ever use Parallel.For ?

Comment: If memory serves, `Parallel.For` doesn't always break the work down into multiple threads, it might run the entire thing on a single thread. You might be viewing the overhead involved in using the `Parallel` methods on lightweight pieces of work, where it is costly to marshal work over threads.

Comment: The actual work you do in each iterartion is not that much, so the cost  of creating and managing and consolidating threads is much higher than the gain you get from parallel proccessing. `Parallel.For` will only be faster when you do a lot more time consuming stuff each round.

Comment: [Have a look at this recent answer where I make some detailed timings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16822242/106159). `Parallel.For()` does work well for small loop bodies if you use a `Partitioner` as I do in that answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the most common mistakes one does, when first delving into multithreading, is the belief, that multithreading is a [Free Lunch](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/concurrency-ddj.htm).

In truth, splitting your operation into multiple smaller operations, which can then run in parallel, is going to take some extra time. If badly synchronized, your tasks may well be spending even more time, waiting for other tasks to release their locks.

As a result; parallelizing is not worth the time/trouble, when each task is going to do little work, which is the case with `OperationDoWork`.

## Edit:

Consider trying this out:

```
    private static void OperationDoWork(int i)
    {
        double a = 101.1D * i;
        for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
            a = Math.Pow(a, a);
    }
```

According to my benchmark, `for` will average to 5.7 seconds, while `Parallel.For` will take 3.05 seconds on my Core2Duo CPU (speedup == ~1.87).
On my Quadcore i7, I get an average of 5.1 seconds with `for`, and an average of 1.38 seconds with `Parallel.For` (speedup == ~3.7).

This modified code scales very well to the number of physical cores available. [Q.E.D.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D)

Answer (score 12):

Parallel processing has organization overhead. Think of it in terms of having 100 tasks and 10 people to do them. It's not easy to have 10 people working for you, just organizing who does what costs time in addition to actually *doing* the 100 tasks.

So if you want to do something in parallel, make sure it's so much work that the workload of *organizing* the parallelism is so small compared to the *actual* workload that it makes sense to do it.

Comment: Very nice explanation. "I'm faster doing it by myself!" is probably an experience everyone had at least once with "teamwork".