# Inlining some events in BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, lambda

Im not sure, but is it called inlining when you do it all in one line?

I my code i have this BackgroundWorker. The DoWorker enforce a sleep of on sec and the RunWorkerCompleted just does noe bit of code. Would it be possible to instead of defining a function do it all in one line like

```
.DoWork += ((sender, arg) => { ... });
```

and

```
.RunWorkerCompleted += ((sender, arg...
```

What is the right syntax for this, and what is this called? Its nice to keep things simple when you have a simple task at hand :-)

Comment: It's called lambda expressions. Inlining means putting method body to code, instead of calling method.

Comment: @wudzik thanks, my googling became alot better now that I know what Im looking for :-)

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/473782/238902)

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `inlining` with `lambda expressions`. 
[Inlining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) is replacing the calling of a method by its body, for example:

```
int TimesTwo(int x) 
{
   return x * 2;
}

//before inlining:
int a = TimesTwo(6) + TimesTwo(7);
//after inlining:
int a = 6 * 2 + 7 * 2;
```

This is a compiler optimization technique to avoid method call overhead.

For your `BackgroundWorker` example the correct syntax would be:

```
 BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
 worker.DoWork += (sender, e) => RunMyMethod();
 //or
 worker.DoWork += (sender, e) => { RunMyMethod(); }
```

For more information see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx).