# Do I need to worry about inlining in Unity/C#?

Tags: c#, optimization, unity-game-engine, inlining

For code clarity I sometimes create a function that should very obviously be inlined, be it either a wrapper, or a function that is only called in a single point, or a short function that is supposed to be called frequently and be *fast*.

In C I would inline it without a second thought, but in Unity/C# there's no way to do that AFAIK ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8746128/207655) appears to be only available at .NET 4.5).

Can I trust the compiler to be smart enough to actually inline smartly, or I'd better sometimes sacrifice code clarity for performance, mistrusting the compiler?

---

Sure it depends case by case, premature optimization is evil, and you should profile instead of guessing. However a general overview of this subject might still be useful as a guideline, to improve upon.

Comment: "In C I would inline it without a second thought" --- modern compilers can ignore your explicit inlining though. Not much difference with C# then? :-)

Comment: @zerkms You can inline it with a macro. I doubt a compiler would somehow un-inline it in this case.

Comment: @Theodoros Chatzigiannakis: it won't be a *function inlining* then. I'm sure op meant using an `inline` keyword.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis 1. macros are ugly: I do this for code clarity, so using macros would defeat the purpose; 2. Unity likely wouldn't support them anyway: it doesn't even support project-wide defines, let alone macros!

Comment: @Lohoris I was referring to macros in C (which force inlining, AFAIK), not to macros in C# (which don't exist). So it wasn't a response to your question, but to the comment. Unfortunately, I don't know of any way to force inlining in C#.

Comment: Never trust the C# compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Manually forcing in-lining in C# at compile time doesn't make much sense. When the code is run the just-in-time compiler can decide to in-line the code based on these heuristics:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/29/64717.aspx

> - Methods that are greater than 32 bytes of IL will not be inlined.
> - Virtual functions are not inlined.
> - Methods that have complex flow control will not be in-lined. Complex flow control is any flow control other than if/then/else; in this case, switch or while.
> - Methods that contain exception-handling blocks are not inlined, though methods that throw exceptions are still candidates for inlining.
> - If any of the method's formal arguments are structs, the method will not be inlined.

If you're absolutely sure that the method has to be in-lined you can use these above heurstics to make the method more appealing to in-line.

MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining is mostly useful for inlining across assembly boundaries, something I do not believe the just-in-time compiler can do (but I'd have to check that).