# What is the fastest way to store information with two integer keys?

Tags: c#, performance

I have got tons of objects, which have **two `Int32` Keys** to identify them in a collection. The question is the choice of collection. The only criteria is **pure performance** for accessing/"reading" an object(no need to be writable).

---

**Stuff I analyzed:**

I didn't try hashtables cause of [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/hashtable).
I had got the idea to try around with following types:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>,object>
Dictionary<long,object> // putting the bytes of two ints together by first*(int.MaxValue+1L)+second
Dictionary<int, List<Tuple<int,object>>
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int,object>>


List<Tuple<int,int,object>>
List<Tuple<long,object>>
List<Tuple<int,Tuple<int,object>>
```

I filled them with 1000 values for the first and 100 values for the second integer. The "object" for testing was `firstInt.ToString()+secondInt.ToString()`

I measured using following pattern:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch st = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        bool b=true;
        st.Start();
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            for (int ii = 0; ii< 1000; ii++)
            {   //for making sure code optimization doesn't jump over it
                b=b&*accessor*.Contains('a');
            }
        }
        st.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Result: "+st.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

I used following accessors:

```
     Dictionary<Tuple<int,int>,object> dir [...]
     Accessor:  dir[a][b]
     Result: 211ms

     Dictionary<long,object> dir [...]
     Accessor: dir[merge(a,b)]
     Result: 70ms

     //method for sticking two ints together
     public static long merge(int a,int b)
     { return (int.MaxValue+1L)*a+b;}

     Dictionary<int, List<Tuple<int,object>> dir[...]
     Accessor:   dir[a].Find(x=>x.Item1==b).Item2
     Result:  15ms

     Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int,object>> dir[...]
     Accessor:   dir[a][b]
     Result:  22ms

     List<Tuple<int,int,object>> dir[...]
     Accessor: dir.Find(x=>x.Item1==a&&x.Item2==b).Item3
     Result: over60s

     List<Tuple<long,object>> dir[...]
     Accessor: dir.Find(x=>x.Item1==merge(a,b)).Item2
     Result: over60s

     List<Tuple<int,Tuple<int,object>> dir[...]
     Accessor: dir.Find(x=>x.Item==a).Item2.Find(x=>x.Item==b).Item2
     Result: over60s
```

**Are there better/faster types? any recommendations about improving the performance? or is there a quite different solution state-of-the-art?**

Comment: How much is a ton of data ? Do you have 100 keys ? 100 000 000 ?

Comment: @nos 2 keys per value, between 1000  and 10 000 values

Comment: @Cyral how should I use `Hashset<T>` ? should I try `Hashset<Tuple<int,int,object> ?`

Comment: @leAthlon Nevermind, for some reason I thought a HashSet was like a dictionary and not a list. In this case, you will need something like a dictionary because it is designed for lookups, using a list will be much slower (as you can tell), because you are trying to use it as a dictionary.

Comment: 1000-10000 values is a small amount. So you can use a dictionary. But if you are looking at millions of values, you will have to use something different and have a different approach to process them.

Comment: I'd at least try out making a custom struct similar to the 211ms `Tuple<int,int>` option with an overloaded/optimized `GetHashCode()` implementation. I don't really expect it to work, but you should be able to approach the 70ms timeframe with the 211ms semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, your second method (`Dictionary<long,object>`) should be the fastest. I think that the biggest issue is the overhead of the method call (which might not be getting inlined by the JIT). There is also a faster way to get the combined `long` from the two int values.

Instead of doing this

```
Accessor: dir[merge(a,b)]
```

Try this:

```
Accessor: dir[(((ulong)(uint)a) << 32) | (uint) b)]
```

Also, according to @JoelCoehoorn's comment below, you can extract the merging process into a separate method and force inlining using the following attribute: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions(v=VS.110).aspx. However, I'd run the benchmark using both ways just to make sure there are no side-effects.

Please post the speed result in the comments; I'd be very curious to see.

Comment: He can still use a function with the new (.Net 4.5) inlining hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473782/inline-functions-in-c

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Good point! I wasn't aware of that. Answer updated.

Comment: That should be `dir[(((ulong)(uint)a) << 32) | (uint) b)]`.  Also the code in the question was wrong because it only shifted by 31 instead of 32.  `(int.MaxValue + 1)` vs `(uint.MaxValue + 1)`

Comment: @BenVoigt Corrected, thanks! As for the second point, yes, I've noticed that too, but I suppose it bears little relevance since he was only benchmarking and not doing actual lookups; further, that's the part rewritten in the answer anyway.