# C# inline lambda expression

Tags: javascript, c#

the title is a mouthful and not even sure it's accurate (couldn't make much sense of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473782/inline-functions-in-c)), so I'll try to explain what I'd like to accomplish in `C#` by using equivalent `javascript`. Any suggestion as to what I should title this question is very much welcome.
In `C#`, say I have defined this function:

```
Func<string, string> getKey = entity => {
    switch(entity) {
        case "a":
            return "foo";
        case "b":
            return "bar";
        default:
            return "baz";
    }
};

string key = getKey(/* "a", "b", or something else */);
```

Now suppose I don't want to define the `getKey` function explicitly, but use it anonymously as I would in this equivalent `javascript` snippet:

```
string key = (function(entity) {
    switch(entity) {
        case "a":
            return "foo";
        case "b":
            return "bar";
        default:
            return "baz";
    }
}(/* "a", "b", or something else */));
```

How would I go about writing that in `C#`? I tried:

```
string key = (entity => {
    switch(entity) {
        case "a":
            return "foo";
        case "b":
            return "bar";
        default:
            return "baz";
    }
})(/* "a", "b", or something else */);
```

but I get syntax error `CS0149: Method name expected`.
Thanks in advance, cheers.

Comment: You can name it C# inline lambda expression

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO, the nearest equivalent is this:

```
var key = new Func<string, string>(entity =>
{
    switch (entity)
    {
        case "a":
            return "foo";
        case "b":
            return "bar";
        default:
            return "baz";
    }
})("a");
```

Comment: @iggymoran I was just about to write the same thing; I tried it first with `("a")` and it worked like a charm, so thanks @Dennis!

Answer (score 0):

C# is a compiled language and thus different from javascript in a number of ways. What you are looking for is a closure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming). And those are possible in C# (for example Linq).

But I think that what you are looking for can be solved nicely with extension methods (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx):

```
using ExtensionMethods;
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("a".ConvertKey());
        }
    }
}

namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static string ConvertKey(this String key)
        {
            switch (key)
            {
                case "a":
                    return "foo";
                case "b":
                    return "bar";
                default:
                    return "baz";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Same program using Linq:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new[] { "a" }.Select(entity =>
            {
                switch (entity)
                {
                    case "a":
                        return "foo";
                    case "b":
                        return "bar";
                    default:
                        return "baz";
                }
            }).First());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

You can think of "Select" as "map" in functional terms. Hope this helps!

Comment: I *knew* it had something to do with closures, cause that's what the equivalent `javascript` code is all about, too. I just chickened out in using the term :)

Comment: About your answer: neat, but way too cumbersome, my whole idea was to *save* code since I only need the closure in that one place; otherwise an extension method would have been my choice as well.

Comment: Alright. You could use Linq to write closures over lists (but they don't work on single values, as you'll see in the example I had to instantiate an array with a single value). Previous program with Linq: