# For "actionSheetAlert", what's after (action) =>

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using Xamarin's ActionSheet Alert function and following the instruction from official website. The sample given by website is shown as

```
actionSheetAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Item One",UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (action) => Console.WriteLine ("Item One pressed.")));
```

After `(action) =>`, it only shows how we can add one function here, which is `(action) => Console.WriteLine ("Item One pressed.")`

What if I want to add more actions? Can I just use `(action) => {......}` ? Or can I use `(action) => function1()`? Could you please show me more examples that I can do after `(action) =>` ?

Comment: `(action) => {......}` will work, and so will `(action) => function1()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried, yes, both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

That's sample code for UIActionSheet, it should can help you.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UIKit;

    namespace TestActionSheet
    {
    public class SimpleSheet
    {
        public delegate void SelectedHandler(string selectedValue);
        public event SelectedHandler Selected;
        private UIActionSheet actionSheet;

        public SimpleSheet(List<string> optionList)
        {
            actionSheet = new UIActionSheet("SheetTitle");
            foreach (string str in optionList)
            {
                actionSheet.Add(str);
            }
            actionSheet.AddButton("Cancel");

            actionSheet.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.ButtonIndex < actionSheet.ButtonCount - 1)
                {
                    if (null != Selected)
                        Selected(optionList[(int)e.ButtonIndex]);
                }
            };
        }

        public void Show(UIView view)
        {
            actionSheet.ShowInView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

And invoke those code like this:

```
SimpleSheet sSheet = new SimpleSheet(new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>() { "option1", "option2" });
                sSheet.Selected += (selectedValue) => {
                    Console.WriteLine("SelectedValue = "+selectedValue);
                };
                sSheet.Show(this.View);
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps. And I also want to ask,

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps. And I also want to ask, is (null != Selected) same with (Selected != null)? If not ,what does it mean? Thx : )

Comment: Nice question, actually there is no different. That's my habit, because my first programing language is C.
For C compiler, it can support the condition like "if(a = 1)" and it means that is true, so to prevent the mistake like " a = 1 "(the correct one is " a == 1"), I prefer to use " 1 == a",  if I make a mistake like " 1 = a " the compiler will give me an error, it can help me to check it.

Comment: Glad to help you and you can mark it as answer if you think it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In short answer, you can do it in both way and achieve the same outcome.

```
actionSheetAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Item One",UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (action) => {
 Console.WriteLine ("Item One pressed.");
 Console.WriteLine (Date.UtcNow);
}));
```

or

```
function messageOutput(){
         Console.WriteLine ("Item One pressed.");
         Console.WriteLine (Date.UtcNow);
    } 

actionSheetAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("ItemOne",UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (action) => messageOutput);
```

In detail answer, you question is not very clear what you are going to achieve. If it is about optimizations of inline function, you can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473782/inline-functions-in-c). Especially, you have mentioned your are using Mono(Xamarin) which has some other consideration.